# How can I make my horizontal linear layouts always LTR regardless of the device language?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

It appears that the direction of the horizontal linear layouts in my app gets changed according to the device language. This is very annoying and causes the app to display incorrectly when the language of the device is RTL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by going to the manifest file and changing the attribute `android:supportsRtl` to false.